# Java ArrayList `clear()` method different than new initializing ArrayList object

Tags: java, arraylist, initialization

I was having the an issue while writing this code and I solved it, but I'm not sure about the reason behind it, so it would be great if someone would explain why it happens.

**The problem is the following:**

`rowData` is an `ArrayList<String>`, and `reportData` is an `ArrayList<ArrayList>`

The code below loops through results from a database, for every row of the query result, `rowData` is appended with the String values of the columns (The for loop) to form a complete row of data, then each row is appended to `reportData`.

```
while(rs.next()) {
    rowData.clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < wrapper.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        rowData.add(rs.getString(i+1));
    }
    System.out.println("rowData being pushed to reportData" + rowData);
    reportData.add(rowData);
}
System.out.println(reportData);
```

Now here's the **problem**: Let's suppose there are 3 rows of data. The first `System.out.println` prints each different row of data correctly. However, when the second one prints, it shows that the `reportData` is **filled with the last row of data 3 times**.

This is solved when I do this:

```
while(rs.next()) {
    //rowData.clear();
    ArrayList<String> rowData = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < wrapper.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        rowData.add(rs.getString(i+1));
    }
    System.out.println("rowData being pushed to reportData" + rowData);
    reportData.add(rowData);
}
System.out.println(reportData);
```

Now the `reportData` is filled correctly. This worked by intuition, but I am not sure exactly why this happens.

Comment: One hopes that the actual type of "`reportData` is an `ArrayList<ArrayList>`" is `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`. Or better yet, `List<List<String>>`.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.